# Python3.5 Time Zone conversion

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.5

I have tried a number of posts/suggestions on here on converting time zone objects and have failed.  I hope someone can point me to an easy way to do this.

I have a string/datetime of `2017-05-11T16:24:56-04:00`
I can parse it a number of ways, dateutil, etc, into a datetime object.
when printed i get

`datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 11, 16, 24, 56, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -14400))`

so it gets a tzoffset.

Trying any conversion doesn't seem to update the actual time portion, just the zone information.

How do I convert this string to my local time zone (EST, or offset -5hrs).

edit: trying astimezone() gets me this:

```
dt.astimezone()                                                                   
Out[18]: datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 11, 16, 24, 56, 
tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 72000), 'EDT'))
```

Thanks!

Comment: [`datetime.astimezone()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone)

Comment: @Norrius tried that, didn't work

Comment: @Norrius perhaps it is working... I think i've mistaken not working, for it realizing i'm at -4 hours because of daylight savings :( trying to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

When you convert it using `tzinfo` you only change the suffix of the output string (e.g. with tzutc()): `2017-05-11 16:24:56+00:00`

If you want to print it in your time zone, first create the datetime object using the actual timezone it represents:

```
dt = datetime(2017, 5, 11, 16, 24, 56,
              tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -18000))
# 2017-05-11 16:24:56-05:00
```

And then convert it to the desired timezone using:

```
mydt = dt.astimezone(tzutc())
# 2017-05-11 21:24:56+00:00
```

Comment: i've been trying that and i think it works, my issue is i'm creating the datetime via parsing a string.  which seems to work with dateutil parser, but having issues getting it converted... however, i think my issue is i didn't realize i'm in UTC-4 due to daylight savings EDT (not EST which is -5).

Comment: @warath-coder, I'm happy it works for you. I'm not sure if you need help with anything else. Are you having issues with parsing the string to a datetime object?

Comment: What is `tzoffset`?

Comment: @JohnMee, it's "time-zone-offset"

Comment: @DanielTrugman yeah the missing piece to that puzzle was that [`tzoffset` belongs to the python-dateutil package](https://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-8bf499d888b70bc300c6c8820dc123326197c00f)